# Code text showing up on page in wordpress

Tags: html, css

I have a button on page 2 of a series of pages on my website. This button when clicked takes you back to page 1. When going back to page 1, I wanted to load at the BOTTOM of the page.

To go back to page 1, I added this to the end of the URL on my button on page 2: #bottom

On page 1, in the bottom field of my page, I added this code:

```
<a name="bottom">bottom</a>
```

Everything is working as I want it to... however, the text BOTTOM is showing up on the page and I obviously don't want it to. Does anyone have any fixes or tips?

Comment: so where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for an anchor.

On the page you want the anchor to be, change the code from

```
<a name="bottom">bottom</a>
```

to

```
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

This defines the anchor. So when you link to it, you would link to `http://example.com/page1#bottom` and it would go to it on load

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much for the help :). Really appreciate it!